# Firebase With Web: Using user Id in reference causes error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an error with fire base reference, for some reason it says the reference is undefined and I cannot figure out why, if you could help in any way that would be great.

```
var eventtable = document.getElementById("eventtable");
var dateofevent = document.getElementById("dateofevent");
var datetext = dateofevent.textContent;
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var firebaseRef;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    var email = user.email;
    userId = user.uid;
    document.getElementById("welcomeuser").innerHTML = "Welcome " + email;
firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Events").child(userId).child(datetext);

} else {
     window.location.href="login.html";
}
});

firebaseRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {

var content = '';

snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    var val = childSnapshot.val();

    content +='<tr>';
    content += '<td>' + val.Name + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.Description + '</td>';
    content += '</tr>';
});
    eventtable.append(content);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use firebaseRef before it has a value.

onAuthStateChanged is asynchronous, meaning it returns immediately, and the callback you pass isn't executed until auth information is available.  This means firebaseRef doesn't have a value until it does get called.  Your code goes on to assume that firebaseRef has a value.

If you want to use firebaseRef, you have to only use it after it's assigned.

Comment: What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Put the `firebaseRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {})` block in the `if (user) {}` one. This way you are sure you have a value for `firebaseRef`.